# Spring Security redirecting custom login page to itself - Too Many Redirects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently developing a custom login-page for my Spring Boot Application but I just can't get it to work. Using the default one works fine but as soon as I try to use my custom file, it just repeatedly redirects me until my Browser give up.

Other posts suggest permitting access to the login-path to erveryone but this also doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

And Controller for login-page

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login () {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a lot of CSS and JS file link links, according to your code Spring Boot must first authenticate all the links, which is why it redirects to your login page many times.

add following code to bypass security authentication of resource link

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/bower_components/**", "/dist/**", "/plugins/**"); //write your resource directory name 
    }
```